# can I insert a cattr_accessor_with_default class method in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have in my Event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base  

   def self.cattr_accessor_with_default(name, value = nil)
     cattr_accessor name
     self.send("#{name}=", value) if value
   end
   cattr_accessor_with_default :fixed_start_end_times, false
   ...
```

As I defined a Scheduler module

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Scheduler
```

It seems I cannot move the  cattr_accessor_with_default method into this Scheduler module

```
module Scheduler
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cattr_accessor_with_default(name, value = nil)
      cattr_accessor name
      self.send("#{name}=", value) if value
     end
    cattr_accessor_with_default :fixed_start_end_times, false
    ...
```

raising an error : 
undefined method `cattr_accessor_with_default' for Scheduler::ClassMethods:Module 
(NoMethodError)

I tried also to use a better Rails3  way

```
 module Scheduler
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
   class_attribute :fixed_start_end_times
   self.fixed_start_end_times = false
```

same error 
 undefined method `class_attribute' for Scheduler::ClassMethods:Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you put `cattr_accessor_with_default` at wrong place. Try following code:

```
module Scheduler
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      cattr_accessor_with_default :fixed_start_end_times, false
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cattr_accessor_with_default(name, value = nil)
      cattr_accessor name
      self.send("#{name}=", value) if value
    end
    ...
```

This way `cattr_accessor_with_default` is sent to the including class, e.g. `class Event`, and `cattr_accessor_with_default` has been added into that class as a class method.

Comment: Thanks ... go to know , even if I moved to writing a better Rails3 implementation

Answer (score 0):

First I created :

```
#lib/scheduler.rb

module Scheduler

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :fixed_start_end_times
    self.fixed_start_end_times = false
  end

  # adding instance methods here
  def foo
     "foo"
  end

  # adding static(class) methods here
  module ClassMethods

      def starting_on(start_date)
        where("CAST( starts_at AS TIME) = ?", Event.db_time(start_date))
      end
  end
end

# including the extension 
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Scheduler)
```

Then I added :

```
in #config/initializers/scheduler.rb
 require "scheduler"
```

et voilà ...